# Integrating Salesforce with AS400

Tags: integration, professional-edition

I am looking to integrate Salesforce (Professional Edition) with AS400 and would like to see any modifications made on records in AS400 should instantaneously reflect in Salesforce and vice versa. For example, if I make a change in a particular field or post a comment on record, then it must show up against that particular record in Salesforce.

So, could anyone suggest me with few options.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have the API, you're pretty much stuck. You'll need Enterprise Edition for real-time replication.

Comment: You can purchase the API access as as Add-on on Professional edition org. but as others have mentioned your options will be very limited even with that.

Comment: Is there any other alternative like using "Jitter Bit" or "ETL" for having the synchronization established.

Comment: Have a look at Skyvva it does need API but has some great ETL features. It will need a windows server to host a very small Java agent to push the XML or text files to Salesforce. Also without record types and page layouts it will be harder to 'lock' field changes for records from the AS400 database.

Answer (score 8):

not much in the way of integration is possible with professional edition. You'll need Enterprise edition at the minimum.

For instantaneous transfer, you'll burn through a lot of api calls, so look at performance edition.

I think you'll probably need to settle on a scheduled set of csv exports every 15 minutes or so.

Actually, I just did a bit of digging and discovered that if your data on the AS/400 machine is a db2 database ... your world just got a lot easier. Tools like Jitterbit, or Informatica can link directly to Salesforce AND ODBC / JDBC databases. You'd have to contact the Jitterbit/informatica guys for details but I think buying one of those tools (which will cost you more than the GDP of Zimbabwe, beware!) will allow you to directly connect them and schedule periodic syncs of data.

Comment: One quick question, how would we be having the "CSV Exports" established both "to and fro" from as400 and Salesforce?

Comment: @Sapthagiri i think i was born After the last as/400 machine was produced so I'm reaching here, but as I understand the as/400 architecture the system relies on a basic ETL (Extract / Transform / Load) process. If you can Extract records and place them somwhere for your integration tool to pick up TO salesforce, then you'll undoubtably be able to pick UP files from that same location that the integration tool writes coming FROM salesforce. At least in theory.

Comment: As APIs are not available in Professional Edition, I think that the only option would be going for Jitter Bit. And I believe that the AS400 machine has got DB2 database.

Comment: In stead of opening a new thread, continuing on this one: @KevinP: AS400 with DB2 database. Would Salesforce Dataloader via CLI be a feasible solution to have one daily batch load? Salesforce Dataloader can load a JDBC driver so technically, a connection towards DB2 would be possible, right? But the DB2 stage should mimick the SFDC data model, I assume.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search brought me [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-integrate-db2-as400-legacy-erp-system-to-salesforce) but as Doug B mentioned below you dont have an access to the API with Professional Edition.

Comment: I believe that SF professional edition doesn't include API access, which means that the approach described in your link - pushing the data into SF - will not be possible.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't pay any attention to what license Sapthagiri was on

Answer (score 1):

I've used Jitterbit to sync records between an AS400 and Salesforce before. You can use Jitterbit with ODBC/JDBC to connect to the AS400 to poll for changes and upload them to Salesforce. For updates from within Salesforce back to the 400, I'd recommend looking at Outbound messages to send them to the Jitterbit server.

Note that you'd need to upgrade to at least Enterprise Edition to be able to do both API and workflow rules with outbound messages.

I know Jitterbit Data Loader works with all editions of Salesforce regardless of if you have API enabled or not, maybe the full version can do it too?

Without spending a lot of money, I'd say try out the Jitterbit Dataloader and set it up to run on a schedule to move the changes both directions.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for reasoning out well. As mentioned above, I am afraid that we have got no APIs and Workflows in Professional Edition. 

Would like to know if there any sample codes/documents which can help in achieving this process via Jitter Bit data loader. I am considerably new to AS400 and Jitter Bit data loader.

Comment: One quick question @Daniel, what would you say about having the integration done via FTP. Like in Salesforce we have the connection established to FTP (to and fro). And similarly, if we have got a to and fro connection between AS400 & FTP. Can't we go with this process to the integration?

Comment: You could go that way I guess, but it seems to have more potential points of failure. If you use Jitterbit with a direct ODBC connection to the AS400 - you have one system that does it all. I think the Jitterbit Data Loader is really easy to use. The hardest part is getting the ODBC connection string set up properly.

Comment: Thanx @Daniel. As I am completely new to as400 and Salesforce integration. I would like to know if you have worked on this type of integration earlier. If so, you could help me out a little bit. And could name out a few risks of using FTP in this case.

Comment: Is it not possible with  Free version of Jitter Bit or do I need to go for a paid version of it.

Comment: It is possible to use the free version  to connect to the AS400 with ODBC or JDBC and push and pull data to Salesforce.

Comment: I am not sure about it as it is a completely new subject for me.

Answer (score 1):

LANSA's Integrator product can provide the integration you require. You can access (C(reate), R(ead), U(pdate), D(elete) Salesforce CRM data directly from RPG programs using simple API calls. You can contact LANSA at 630-874-7000.