# Can the Salesforce Apex Connector Framework allow Salesforce to connect to an AS400 ODBC database?

Tags: apex

Can the Salesforce Apex Connector Framework allow Salesforce to connect to an AS400 ODBC database? If so, how would that be specified?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating Salesforce with AS400](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/integrating-salesforce-with-as400)

Comment: Check this.. Might be helpful...     https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008o3OIAQ..

Answer (score 5):

No. The Connector Framework has to connect to a web URI for the data. ODBC isn't addressable over the web. You need some kind of middleware installed that can use the ODBC connection and expose that to Salesforce in some way.

Rather than build your own Apex classes, I'd recommend looking at using a middleware tool such as Jitterbit or Mulesoft and then using Salesforce Connect to consume the data.